# how to get more than one max records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, max

This is the answers that I want to get.But if I used MAX() function in MySQL, it just return one record.How to handle it?

```
A_plus  ID
2     12345
2     45678
```

As decribed above,The SQL I used as fellow,but it just return one record.

```
SELECT MAX(A_plus_Num) AS A_plus, ID FROM
(SELECT COUNT(grade) AS A_plus_Num,ID FROM take WHERE grade = 'A+'GROUP BY ID) AS temp


A_plus  ID
2      12345
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, the query is a bit more complicated.  One method is using two subqueries with aggregation:

```
select t.*
from (select t.id, count(*) as A_plus
      from take t
      where t.grade = 'A+'
      group by t.id
     ) t
where t.A_plus = (select max(A_plus)
                  from (select t.id, count(*) as a_plus
                        from take t
                        where t.grade = 'A+'
                        group by t.id
                       )
                 );
```